# SharePoint Online Broken Link Checker

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am in search of a broken link scanner for my SharePoint Online tenant.  So far the only company offering anything like this that I can find is Cognillo (formerly QI Point).  They have this as part of a larger solution that I don't need anything else from.

I have seen some articles where people wrote PowerShell scripts to do this, but I'm looking for something more polished.

Back with "on-prem" I was able to use a 3rd party tool with a lot of exclusions, but the validation does not work with SharePoint Online.

**Does anyone know of any other Broken Link checkers that will work with the validation of SharePoint Online?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tried the trial of Replace Magic Ultimate edition. This tool works with SharePoint Online. It scans and provide you report of your broken links for the documents stored in a SharePoint Online Document Library.

https://www.replacemagic.com/ReplaceMagicUltimate.aspx

Me and my team also tried Cognillo but can't test the fixing of broken links because it is asking to purchase license first.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a solution before that will check the URL's but it would be based off a View and one Sharepoint List at a time. It involves simply using JS to ping the URL's and give a status back which can be done a few different ways.